# omitted object after "want" - anything you want

Tags: relative-clauses

What object is omitted after "want" below?

> You can do anything you want.

Since "anything" is the antecedent of the relative clause, is "anything" omitted after "want"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Elliptically, it's the verb *to do* that is omitted:

> You can do anything you want *[to do]*.

But since it is assumed to exist, repeating it is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your post. I have one more question. Can you teach me what sentences are combined with a relative pronoun here?

Comment: @jinnyk216 You should ask that as a separate question, and try to narrow it down. As it stands, it's too broad for there to be a good answer.